# Reading Words from a textbox input

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

so i'm writing a script in Visual Basic 2013 that will be able to recognize the words i type into it. for example, let's say my program says "Hello, what is your name?", and you respond with " My name is Dave, what is yours?" i want to be able to separate the words into different strings or textboxes for the program to analise the syntax. looking back at the example, it would separate each word, and would see the descriptor for the noun 'My' as 'Dave' which is classified as a 'name' and will be sorted as the user's name and used for future statements involving the user's name.

i'm sorry if it's a lengthy/wordy explanation, but i'm still pretty new to coding in general. thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you looking for a way to get all words as multiple strings only or you want the other logic too through which you will match the descriptor for the noun and extract the name?

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to split it into a collection of strings so that you can analyse them one by one (as I assume you would want to).

---

This can easily be done by taking the input text/sentence from a text-box:

In VB:

```
Dim sInput as string = txtMyTextbox.Text 'Whatever your text box name is.
```

In C#:

```
string sInput = txtMyTextbox.Text; // Whatever your text box name is.
```

---

This we can then split:

In VB:

```
Dim strWords as String() = sInput.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.None)
```

In C#:

```
List<string> strWords = sInput.Split(' ').ToList();
```

---

You can then take this list of words and process them one by one:

In VB:

```
For Each(sWord as string in strList)    
    // Evaluate the word against my criteria.
next
```

In C#:

```
foreach (string sWord in strList)
{
    // Evaluate the word against my criteria.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like a C language. i'm talking about visual basic :( sorry

Comment: It is C#, however I will translate for you shortly.